# Paramiko hangs after connecting to custom shell

Tags: python

I have the following script to connect to an custom ssh shell.
When I execute the script it just hangs. It doesnt execute the command. I suspect problems with the shell because it does not have any prompt. Do you have any idea?

```
import sys
import os
import paramiko


ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('10.115.130.22', username='admin', password='xxx', timeout = 30)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('xconfiguration SystemUnit Name: devicename')
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()`
```

Comment: what happens if you change command to something simpler, such as `ps aux` for example?

Answer (score 2):

I spent *way* too much time on this problem. I found that I needed to use the invoke_shell() to be able to get anything past the greeting banner on the Tandberg C/E series video endpoints. Here's my working code, FWIW:

```
import time
import paramiko

command = 'help'

host = 'x.x.x.x'
port = 22
user = 'admin'
passwd = 'TANDBERG'

def tbgShell(host,port,username,password,cmd):
    """send an arbitrary command to a Cisco/TBG gizmo's ssh and 
    get the result"""
    transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
    transport.connect(username = user, password = passwd)
    chan = transport.open_channel("session")
    chan.setblocking(0)
    chan.invoke_shell()

    out = ''

    chan.send(cmd+'\n')

    tCheck = 0

    while not chan.recv_ready():
        time.sleep(1)
        tCheck+=1
        if tCheck >= 6:
            print 'time out'#TODO: add exeption here
            return False
    out = chan.recv(1024)

    return out

output = tbgShell(host, port, user, passwd, command)

print output
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a custom shell. It is a cisco ex90 video conferencing system.
But I tried different commands like xconfig which show you the config.